# Insert line in nginx configuration file ansible inside http {}

Tags: nginx, centos, ansible

I am writing an ansible script to deploy django in centos 7. My problem is with nginx.

I have created /etc/nginx/sites-available and /etc/nginx/sites-enabled directories and have to include sites-available in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf file at the bottom if http { } block.

How do I insert the line `include /etc/nginx/sites-available/*.conf` inside the http {} block in my ansible script after creating the respective directories and copying the configuration files?

The output should be

```
http {
    .....
    .....

    server {
        .......
    }

    include /etc/nginx/sites-available/*.conf;
}
```

Comment: You mean sth like http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/template_module.html ?

Comment: @Wtower The template might not work as I expect. I am going with lineinfile for now

Comment: "might not work as I expect"? lineinfile will cause a lot more pain.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [lineinfile module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/lineinfile_module.html). Something like this should work:

```
- lineinfile: dest=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf regexp="^include /etc/nginx/sites-available/*.conf;" insertbefore="server {" line="include /etc/nginx/sites-available/*.conf;"
```

This will insert the line before the server block. You can play around with insertbefore and insert after and different regular expressions.

Comment: I think the issue with this is this has the potential to insert more than one line if there's more than one `server {` phrase defined in the default config.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `lineinfile` you will regret it at some point. Everybody does.

You should create a template and then load that with ansible.

```
#file: templates/nginx.conf.j2
http {
    .....
    .....

    server {
        .......
    }

    include /etc/nginx/sites-available/*.conf;
}

#file: main.yml
- name: "Load nginx config"
  template: src=nginx.conf.j2 dest=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

This will make the management of your config much easier if you need to change anything in the config file.

Docs: [Template Module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/template_module.html)

Comment: I did not want to copy the whole nginx.conf file to a template just to add the include line. Are you advising that its the better solution that lineinfile?

Comment: yes, believe me, you will regret using `lineinfile` at some point ;) Having nginx.conf as a template is good anyway, you might want to change something later and you will have to do it anyway :)